# Time-based 32-bit overflow in Java? Or SLES11?

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat6, sles, sles11

This is Tomcat 6.0.18, Java 1.7.0_03 (32-bit), and SLES11 SP2 (64-bit).  As for kernel information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux server-1 3.0.13-0.27-default #1 SMP Wed Feb 15 13:33:49 UTC 2012 (d73692b) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

We were doing a load and longevity test on three servers.  On all three separate machines we had Tomcat exit within **one second** of 2^32 milliseconds (49+ days) of when each Tomcat started up.  On each machine two threads produced stack traces before the JVM exits (Tomcat itself calls `System.exit(1)` when it gets the `SocketTimeoutException` which is why the JVM exits).

One thread is the one that (by default) listens on port 8005 for the shutdown command (verified that by looking at Tomcat source):

```
Jun 22, 2012 9:10:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: accept: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:389)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:642)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:602)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
```

The other thread is (we believe, though we didn't check Tomcat source to verify) the one that handles incoming port 8080 connections:

```
Jun 22, 2012 9:10:15 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket acceptConnections
WARNING: Exception executing accept
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
      at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
      at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
      at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.accept(ChannelSocket.java:307)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.acceptConnections(ChannelSocket.java:661)
      at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketAcceptor.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:872)
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tomcat isn't doing anything wild.  In the first case it's just a `while (true)` loop that gets a `Socket` by calling `ServerSocket.accept()` and the `accept()` call bombs out.

Any ideas why this is happening and what I could try to look at/for to figure out how to prevent it in the future?

Note that while *Tomcat* was running for 2^32 milliseconds, the system had already been up when Tomcat was started.  Of course that doesn't rule out some process variable that was created when Tomcat started being involved.

Comment: It appears [Tomcat 6.0.18](http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-6/) was released in 2008, well before Java 1.7, although there are some socket [incompatibilities b/w Java 1.6 & 1.7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) nothing jumps out to explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've recently seen this problem as well and it appears to be isolated to a change made in the 32-bit Oracle JVM between Java 6 and 7.  On Linux, running the 32-bit Java 7 VM with strace shows the following system call when ServerSocket.accept() is invoked without having set SO_TIMEOUT:

```
32369 poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLERR}], 1, 4294967295 <unfinished ...>
```

The call to poll() passes a timeout value of 2^32 milliseconds (4294967295), rather than the expected negative value which would indicate an infinite timeout. This eventually causes ServerSocket.accept() to throw a SocketTimeoutException, which causes Tomcat's bootstrap code to perform a shutdown of the server.  That particular piece of Tomcat never expects a SocketTimeoutException to be thrown by ServerSocket.accept.

It is easier to reproduce this problem if the call to poll() can be manipulated so that you don't have to wait 2^32 milliseconds.  This can be done in Linux by overriding the poll system call.  One method for doing this involves using the LD_PRELOAD directive to load an overridden version of poll. Some example code that shows this idea can be found at https://github.com/vi/timeskew.  Unfortunately, it does not override poll, but can be readily extended to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the same problem using Tomcat 7.0.35 with Java 1.7.0_10 (32bit) on a 64-bit Debian Linux.

In my case updating and using the 64bit JDK solved this problem

Comment: Updating to 64-bit Java fixed the problem for us as well.  So I assume that somewhere in the C/C++ guts of Java it's using an `int` instead of a `long` to track something.